# ggplot time series, error:Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type xts/zoo. Defaulting to continuous

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, google-finance

I'm new to ggplot and, while this seems like a simple question, I'm baffled.  I get the error message

> Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type xts/zoo.
>   Defaulting to continuous.

And I don't see a line on my graph.  Here's the output : 
[image: ggplot output]
Here's my code:

```
> library(quantmod)
> library(TTR)
> library(ggplot2)
> getSymbols("SPY")
[1] "SPY"
> price<-SPY[,1]
> ggplot(price,aes(x=time(price),y=price),geom_line(color="blue"))
```

Comment: ggplot likes data.frames. Also you need to have `ggplot(...) + geom_line(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

zoo provides `autoplot.zoo` to plot xts/zoo objects with ggplot2:

```
autoplot(price, col = I("blue")) + ggtitle("SPY")
```

Also check out `chart_Series` (from quantmod) which uses classic graphics:

```
chart_Series(SPY)
```